# Need jQuery selector for hidden form element

Tags: jquery

This is a part of my HTML form:

```
<form name = 'myform'>
  <input type='button' name='mybutton' value='Activate'>
  <input type='hidden' name='myhidden' value='elementvalue'>
```

I want to send the value of the hidden element to the server when the user clicks the 'Activate' button by using Ajax. Here is [a snippet that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266701/processing-twitter-bootstrap-events-with-flask), but  I need to change this part:

```
$("input[name=choice1]").val(this.value);
```

in order to select my hidden element value and I don't know how.

At this moment I'm learning Python, Flask/Jinja2 and HTML/CSS at the same time, so diving into jQuery as well is just too much right now.

Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @dda, I noticed you went through some effort to clean up my post. Not that I'm offended or anything, but just to learn: is there some meaning I should derive from that? Did I break some unwritten rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[name=myhidden]").val(this.value);
```

just modify the selector.  see the docs http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: This led to a working solution after some experimenting. I still don't fully understand why I can pass variables to the server-side function using any name for the 'data' element of the jQuery post-method, but that's for another time.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("input[type=hidden]")
```

it will select all the hidden elements from your form.